# Why do I get a Swift compiler error when importing Vapor?

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

I have tested everything, all is up and running. However, when I import Vapor in a new file I get a Swift compiler error when I try to build the web app. As soon as I remove `import Vapor` from my newly created Swift file everything goes back to normal and runs. Can you please explain to my why this happens?

This is the Swift file:

```
import Foundation
import Vapor



struct apple{
    var id: Int = 0

    init(id: Int){
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Swift Compiler Error, Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 @OlegGordiichuk

Comment: found the source of the problem, thank you for your time. @OlegGordiichuk

Comment: Share you're solution please. Probably you will save time for others.

Comment: Working on it @OlegGordiichuk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening a Swift file that imports Vapor, in the file inspector it must only belong to your app:

[image]

Also do a clean build (command+shift+k) after you choose "App" as your only option.